# Как сделать карусель фото на сайте?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css, карусель

как сделать карусель фото, обязательно зацикленную!
карусель должны выглядеть так: http://gyazo.com/31dc28b0dc22dc8c02e33c9e61b35bfc
то бишь две стрелки по бокам, внутри, скажем, 3 изображения (но из на самом деле больше. 30 скажем)
одно но, за один элемент принимать это:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1"
href="img/blag/'.$i.'.jpg">     <img
src="img/blag/'.$i.'.jpg" height=200>
</a>
```

Благодарю!

Comment: Эта штука точно умеет:
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/
Вот пример:
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой и лёгкий вариант: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

Вариант более интересный, функциональный, адаптивный и работающий на тач-устройствах: https://iosscripts.com/iosslider/

Если используете бутстрап: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

И ещё множество вариантов: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+carousel

Comment: Если хотите показать результаты своей работы, лучше на jsfiddle.net

Comment: готово http://jsfiddle.net/Mfh7G/1/

Comment: а где стили?

http://jsfiddle.net/Mfh7G/3/

Comment: так, я понял, в чем разница между ваши и моим. причина, почему не работает: лишний код. но мне нужно, что бы он тоже был. без него я не могу. как быть? 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none'
 });

 $(function() {
  $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
   btnNext: ".next",
   btnPrev: ".prev"
  })
 })     
});

Comment: да, так и есть, удаляю этотвыделенный код, и все работает. возвращаю - не работает: http://gyazo.com/390f44b13765f8ed6bc1034d4bccd03d.png

Comment: вам бы разобраться в том, что делает каждая из строк кода, и научиться пользоваться инструментами вроде файрбага или веб-инспектора.

Возвращаю удалённый вами код, и всё работает: http://jsfiddle.net/Mfh7G/4/

Найдите ещё три отличия.

Comment: отличия нашел. большое спасибо за помощь, Елена! загуглил файрбаг, полезная шутка, буду пользоваться

Comment: отлично. Успехов! :)

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую [Фотораму](http://artpolikarpov.ru/projects/fotorama/#1).

Comment: спасибо, интересное решение

Answer (score 0):

Owl carousel - отличный плагин
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/