# Как переключать проекты с галереей которые представлены в виде карусели

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема, у меня проект с архитектурной тематикой. Раздел с работами представлен в виде галереи проектов.При нажатии на ссылку-картинку с названием проекта выезжает карусель с изображениями - проектов 6. Не могу понять как сделать переключение между ними (фактически между галереями) с помощью стрелок "Следующий проект" "Предыдущий проект".
Здесь тестовая версия сайта http://archaspetto.ru/test/
Помогите пожалуйста, очень нужно!

```
<!-- ссылки на галереи проектов-->
    <div class="wrapper">
     <figure>
        <img src="" alt="">
     </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src=""alt="">
    </figure>
   </div>

 <!-- Проект 1 -->
   <div class="work-tab" id="work1">
      <div class="work-slider">
        <div class="slick-carousel work-slide">
          <div><img src="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div><img src=""  class="img-responsive"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>

 <!-- Проект 1 -->
   <div class="work-tab" id="work1">
      <div class="work-slider">
        <div class="slick-carousel work-slide">
          <div><img src="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div><img src=""  class="img-responsive"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/Gerasimov/pen/qYpbEV

Comment: Мне кажется вопросы про карусель на so уже были и не раз. Воспользуйтесь поиском.

Comment: Полистайте список тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать карусель фото на сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/286855/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Карусель реализована с помощью плагина Slick. Проблема в том как перелистывать эти карусели которые в свою очередь содержат галереи проектов

Comment: Из списка, вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731560/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-slick-%d0%b2-chrome пример с slick, подходит?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Мне нужно каким то образом переключать эти проекты которые содержат фотографии в карусели. Что то на подобие переключения табов с помощью стрелок..

Comment: Если в каждом проекте по две картинки, можно объединить все проекты в один слайдер, а стрелками переключать по два слайда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант передавать стрелкам номера проектов (предыдущего и следующего) при выводе текущей галереи, например, текущий проект при клике имеет индекс n (#work3), тогда предыдущий n-1(#work2), а следующий n+1(#work4),
т.е. ссылки на стрелках галереи work3, например, будут иметь вид:

```
<a href="#work2" class=" arrow left"></a>
...
<a href="#work4" class=" arrow right"></a>
```

на сайте уже есть обработчик этих стрелок, надо только добавлять номера галерей #workN в href

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Comment: Если ответ вам помог отметьте его как верный, пожалуйста. Галочка под голосованием за ответ.